# Passing single pointer and double pointer to a function in c

Tags: c, function, pointers, malloc, function-pointers

I am trying to pass a **single pointer** and **double pointer** in a function. but its giving me error.

```
int main()
{
    int *pt;

    fun(pt);
    .
    .
}

fun(int *pt)
{
    pt=(int*)malloc(6*sizeof(int));
    .
    .
}
```

and what is the syntax when we are using double pointer. Can anybody just describe it with an example or can edit the above example. I shall be very thankful to you.

Comment: You say it's giving you an error. What error is it giving? Also, what does the tutorial you're following say about pointers to pointers?

Comment: Your main is wrong. You mean `int main(void)`. There are no double pointers here. If you have a program that has an error, show that program and include the error verbatim.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "double pointer"? Do you mean you want `fun` to modify the pointer in such a way that `main` receives that modification (which, if done through `fun`s arguments, would be a pointer to a pointer)?

Comment: actually i have to pass matrices in the form pointers to a function. i have to use sing pointer *ptr and double **ptr matrices. but i dont know the exact way how to pass them...i am using it in some other software that has built in C programing. so i cant tell you about the error. just want to know how can we pass matrices in function and than dereference tham by using malloc. thankyou for replying

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fundamental idea of **reference semantics** is that a function modifies some *other* object that exists outside the function's own scope. You can implement reference semantics in C by passing the address of the object that is being referenced to a function that takes an argument of type "pointer to the type of the object".

The crucial hallmark of "reference semantics via pointers" consists of these two points:

- The caller takes the address of something (via the `&`-operator).
- The callee dereferences the argument.

For example:

**Caller:**

```
T x;
f(&x);         // address-of
```

**Callee:**

```
void f(T * p)  // take argument as pointer
{
    (*p).y = 20;  // dereference (via *)
    p->x = 10;    // dereference (via ->)
}
```

---

In your situation, `T = int *`:

```
int * pt;
fun(&pt);              // function call takes address

void fun(int ** p)     // function takes pointer-to-object...
{
    *p = malloc(173);  // ...and dereferences to access pointee
}
```