# Swap the pointers of two arrays in a function

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, swap

I'm writing a mergesort without the copy part into an extra temp array. For this reason, I create an auxiliary array `aux`

```
int * aux
aux = (int *) calloc(n, sizeof(int));
```

where `n` is the size of the array. In the function merge, I want to swap both arrays at the end by using their pointer to continue with my algorithm. But if I swap the pointers, and print them to console, I got weird stuff:

Within the method itself, the pointers are swapped. But if I check after my method, back in my main, the pointers aren't swapped anymore.
The call of my merge method:

```
merge(a, lo, mid, hi, aux);
```

where `a` is my main array, `aux` the auxiliary and `lo`, `mid` and `hi` are integers.

prototype:

```
void merge(int *a, int lo, int mid, int hi, int *aux);
```

I tried to swap them like this:

```
int temp;
temp = a;
a = aux;
aux = temp;
```

Can you help me solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Essentially a [duplicate of this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23449838/596781).

Comment: I disagree on the duplicate, and nominated this question for reopening. This is a very focused question that is also a useful self-contained example, unlike the "duplicate".

Comment: I'm voting to reopen too, because the answers of the duplicate don't directly answer this question. Kerrek SB's linked answer is very good, but the question there is not as good as this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs because the pointers are passed by value.

Change them to pointers to pointers:

```
void merge(int **a, int lo, int mid, int hi, int **aux);
```

Swap like this:

```
int *temp;
temp = *a;
*a = *aux;
*aux = temp;
```

`merge` should then be called like this:

```
merge(&a, lo, mid, hi, &aux);
```

Comment: This is a C question. No references.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about that.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply.
now, i got the following problem:
i can access *a[0], but cannot access *a[1] in the merge function...
Am i too dumb for C ? :(

Comment: You can **either** use a temporary local pointer `int * pa = *a` and use `pa` like `a` before: `pa[1]`,  **or** use `(*a)[1]`

Comment: Finally solved it, thanks alot!!!

Answer (score 0):

I can spot 2 different problems with your approach:

1) Why are you using an int temporary variable to exchange int* pointers? This may cause issues if sizeof(int) != sizeof(int*), for example 64 bits systems. Why not using an int* temporary?

2) your a pointer in:

```
void merge(int *a, int lo, int mid, int hi, int *aux);
```

is passed by value, which means whatever changes you do on the pointer's value in your function will not be visible outside of it. You should rather use one of these approaches:

```
void merge(int **a, int lo, int mid, int hi, int *aux);
```

or:

```
void merge(int *& a, int lo, int mid, int hi, int *aux);
```

if you're in the c++ world.

Another thing: Passing the aux to the merge function may be somewhat redundant since you can very well allocate and deallocate it inside.