# pointers with strings in c programming

Tags: c, string, pointers, pass-by-reference

In the below program, I was expecting the printf statement to print

> a = b, b = a

But, actually it's printing

> a=a, b=b

When I try to print `a`, `b` values inside function, it's giving `a=b,b=a:::I` do not understand why pass be reference is not influencing the actual arguments. What am I missing? Can someone please illustrate?

```
void swap_pointers(char* a, char* b) {
    char* tmp = a;
    a = b;
    b = tmp;
}

int main() {
    char* a = "a";
    char* b = "b";
    swap_pointers(a, b);
    printf("a = %s, b = %s", a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: See: [Swap the pointers of two arrays in a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23909134/swap-the-pointers-of-two-arrays-in-a-function?lq=1)

Comment: Pointers (like any value) are *not* passed with [Call by Reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_reference) semantics in C.

Comment: You should declare every single pointer in this example as `const`.

Answer (score 4):

You're only changing the values of the function arguments within the function. if you want to change the address stored by a pointer that is passed as an argument, you would need to pass a pointer to that pointer.

```
void swap_pointers(char** a, char** b) {
    char* tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;
}
```

Then you call it like this

```
int main() {
    char* a = "a";
    char* b = "b";
    swap_pointers(&a, &b);
    printf("a = %s, b = %s", a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

What's happening here is, in the function you are setting tmp to the *value at* a, then the *value at* a to the *value at* b, and the *value at* b to tmp by using the dereference operator "*".  And when you pass int the arguments, you are passing the *address of* a and the *address of* b with the address operator "&". So in the function you set the value at(*) the address of (&) a variable. And that variable is itself a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

The pointer ("reference" of "pass by reference") is passed by value. If you want to change the reference, you need to pass the *reference* by reference: `(char **a, char **b)`, and have pointer-to-pointer-to-char variables that you would be able to switch. Your function would work for swapping contents of those pointers; but it can't swap pointers themselves.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
void swap_pointers(char *a, char *b) {
    char tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;
}



int main() {
    char a = 'a';
    char b = 'b';
    swap_pointers(&a,&b);
    printf("a = %c, b = %c", a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: first you were changing the address not the value assigned to it

Comment: Try to use proper formatting in code, as well as some explanations. Only code block is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a very simple and a basic problem, related to function calls.

When you do this `swap_pointers(a, b);`,

it actually passes the copies of `a` and `b` to the function;

which does get swapped inside the function.

But, then you do nothing inside the function and the control is returned back to the `main`.

As a result, there has not been made any change inside the `main`.

This is what you are experiencing. The solution to your problem is to use **call by reference**.

As, it has already been suggested by *user2864740* in a comment and explained by *Dave* in his answer.